# Postgres empty directories and GitHub

Tags: postgresql, git, github

**EDIT: Some context was missing from the original question.
My goal in using Git was to share the table structure and stored procedures of a mostly empty database under development with a second person building a REST API server**

Git does not track empty directories, but PostgreSQL requires them at startup.  How can I get the two working together?

Every search I make on the topic brings me to some variation of a Git workaround that involves adding dummy files to directories that would otherwise be empty.  However, PostgreSQL did not appreciate that solution in at least the pg_tblspc directory.

The directories required by PostgreSQL at startup are:

- pg_notify
- pg_tblspc
- pg_replslot
- pg_twophase
- pg_stat
- pg_snapshots
- pg_commit_ts
- pg_logical/mappings
- pg_logical/snapshots

I am running PostgreSQL from a Docker container as follows:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    build: ./pg_db/
    image: db_MyDB
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pg_db/db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

./pg_db/Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:14

ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
ENV POSTGRES_USER=<admin password>
ENV POSTGRES_DB=db_MyDB
```

Then in the CLI...

```
git add .
git commit -m "something"
git push -u origin HEAD
```

Later, if I or another user then try to replicate the database on GitHub from the CLI...

```
git clone https://github.com/<user>/<project>.git
cd <project>
docker-compose -up
```

The result is a set of startup failures related to the missing, empty, directories listed above.  Once I manually create them, PostgreSQL starts up, without any issues to my knowledge.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid running `initdb`? I can't quite see why you would do that. Or what this has to do with git come to think of it.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Thank you for responding, perhaps more ignorance than avoidance. The trouble with Git is tracking empty directories PostgreSQL needs.

When you say I'm avoiding initdb are you implying that I should avoid using images?

My preference for using the Docker image was that it was dead easy for me to get started, and I like the idea of being platform agnostic. Also, I am of the understanding that if I want to explore Kubernetes at a later date, I'll need an image, and starting from an image seemed like a good idea.

Comment: The question is why would want Git to track what is happening in the Postgres $DATADIR anyway?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Interesting.  Test data is trash, but if I exclude the $DATADIR what then is best practice for sharing table structure and stored procedures with a second person working on a REST API server?  This is my first time trying to work with a second person.  Seems apparent that my fundamental thinking on how to do it is flawed.  I want a second person to be able access and build off of the database work I've done locally, I thought passing a Docker file and $DATADIR through Git was correct. If not, what then?  No spoon feeding, just please get me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You won't find that information in $DATADIR  in a text format anyway. It would be buried in the binary data. The way to do this is set up a directory that contains the text scripts for these objects. I personally use [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org/), but there are a host of SQL change management options out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking it is best to keep the schema object definitions in text files external to the database in some sort of change management framework. This can either be a home grown solution or one of the many existing solutions as shown in your link [Change Management](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Change_management_tools_and_techniques). In either case keeping this under version control e.g. Git is an extra layer of flexibility and redundancy.

The basic principle is to have schema(database object) definitions that live outside the database itself. Then have a procedure to apply those definitions or changes to existing definitions in an orderly fashion. Preferably in a way that allows you to both move forward to a new state as well as revert to previous state in the database itself. A version control tool over this works to maintain a history of changes to the schema as well as the other text, code, etc that goes along with any project. It also allows for branching to try out new ideas without interfering with an existing setup.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Richard and Adrian for responding so promptly.

**EDIT: Adrian highlights in a comment below that Git is a strong compliment to a Schema Management Tool**

Git is the wrong tool.  What I need is a Schema Management Tool several of which are highlighted in the PostgreSQL wiki here:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Change_management_tools_and_techniques

Some context was missing from the original question.

My goal in using Git was to share the table structure and stored procedures of a mostly empty database under development with a second person building a REST API server. My approach of sharing the entire data directory caused some confusion and in hindsight I can see how pushing likely stale data around with schema changes would would be a terrible idea in most scenario's.

I have what I need, but if anyone would like to provide a more inciteful answer for anyone else who might wind up here in a search I'd be happy to accept your answer as the correct one.

Comment: Git is not the wrong tool, you can use it to track changes to schema scripts by itself. Or you can run it over a schema migration tool. Either way you want to include it in the mix.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll edit above.  If you post a brief answer I'll accept it.  Thank you again!